# Крокозябры в sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Здравствуйте. Есть небольшая проблема с отображением кодировки в sqlplus. Вот скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что с этим можно сделать что бы была нормальная кодировка?

Answer (score 0):

в командной строке
`chcp 1251`
`sqlplus`
предварительно изменив Шрифт на Lucida Console
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да если через командную строку вызывать sqlplus это помогает. Но если я запускаю на прямую файл sqlplus.exe там всё равно кракозябры.

Answer (score 0):

В реестре измените значение NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_CIS.CL8MSWIN1251
и поменяете по умолчанию язык диагностических сообщений об ошибках и строку приглашения.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]